# Populating DataFrame column depending on multiple rows of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause, multiple-conditions

I have a DataFrame nplt:

```
nplt
Out[120]: 
     sexage  npark16cd  population  page
0       M00  E26000001  146.631840   NaN
1       M01  E26000001  122.677630   NaN
2       M02  E26000001  127.645516   NaN
3       M03  E26000001  138.313014   NaN
4       M04  E26000001  150.898252   NaN
5       M05  E26000001  149.086291   NaN
6       M06  E26000001  145.075953   NaN
7       M07  E26000001  159.893446   NaN
8       M08  E26000001  149.886962   NaN
9       M09  E26000001  182.406901   NaN
10      M10  E26000001  182.058425   NaN
11      M11  E26000001  186.962104   NaN
12      M12  E26000001  200.875284   NaN
13      M13  E26000001  209.038917   NaN
14      M14  E26000001  163.530837   NaN
15      M15  E26000001  161.171527   NaN
```

I wish to populate column page conditional on sexage, for example, where sexage equals M00, M01, M02, M03 I wish page to be p0_3 and where sexage equals M04, M05, M06 I wish page to be p4_6, continuously, like:

```
nplt
Out[120]: 
     sexage  npark16cd  population  page
0       M00  E26000001  146.631840   p0_3
1       M01  E26000001  122.677630   p0_3
2       M02  E26000001  127.645516   p0_3
3       M03  E26000001  138.313014   p0_3
4       M04  E26000001  150.898252   p4_6
5       M05  E26000001  149.086291   p4_6
6       M06  E26000001  145.075953   p4_6
7       M07  E26000001  159.893446   NaN
8       M08  E26000001  149.886962   NaN
9       M09  E26000001  182.406901   NaN
10      M10  E26000001  182.058425   NaN
11      M11  E26000001  186.962104   NaN
12      M12  E26000001  200.875284   NaN
13      M13  E26000001  209.038917   NaN
14      M14  E26000001  163.530837   NaN
15      M15  E26000001  161.171527   NaN
```

and so on. The sexage column in my actual DataFrame ranges from M00-M90 and F00-F90.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

To try and explaining more clearly, I would like the equivalent for both series F00, F01, F02, and F03 and M00, M01, M02 and M03 to have the value p0_3 in page and for M04, M05, M06 and F04, F05 and F06 to have value p4_6 for page. For example:

```
nplt
    Out[120]: 
         sexage  npark16cd  population  page
    0       M00  E26000001  146.631840   p0_3
    1       M01  E26000001  122.677630   p0_3
    2       M02  E26000001  127.645516   p0_3
    3       M03  E26000001  138.313014   p0_3
    4       M04  E26000001  150.898252   p4_6
    5       M05  E26000001  149.086291   p4_6
    6       M06  E26000001  145.075953   p4_6
    7       M07  E26000001  159.893446   p7_10
    8       M08  E26000001  149.886962   p7_10
    9       M09  E26000001  182.406901   p7_10
    10      M10  E26000001  182.058425   p7_10
    11      M11  E26000001  186.962104   NaN
    12      M12  E26000001  200.875284   NaN
    13      M13  E26000001  209.038917   NaN
    14      M14  E26000001  163.530837   NaN
    15      M15  E26000001  161.171527   NaN


2355    F80  W18000003  102.553290   nan
2356    F81  W18000003  115.013810   nan
2357    F82  W18000003   94.524735   p82_85
2358    F83  W18000003   77.677229   p82_85
2359    F84  W18000003  103.239723   p82_85
2360    F85  W18000003   82.496796   p82_85
2361    F86  W18000003   71.609379   p86_90
2362    F87  W18000003   83.220993   p86_90
2363    F88  W18000003   80.120960   p86_90
2364    F89  W18000003   65.742056   p86_90
2365    F90  W18000003  204.664775   p86_90
```

I would like the groupings in M00-M90 and F00-F90 (p0_4, p4_6, p7_10 ... p86_90) to be the same. The values in column page wil be sampling strata in future code.

The reason that there are different numbers of members in column page is vecause these are based on age groups that have varying ranges, for example, 0-3, 4-6, 5-7, 8-12, 13, 14-18 ... all the way up to 90.

I have tried:

```
nplt.loc[(nplt['sexage'] == {'M00', 'M01', 'M02', 'M03', 'F00', 'F01',
                  'F02', 'F03'}), 'page'] = 'p0_3'
```

However it does not work. Any help is greatly appreciate please.

Comment: How are we supposed to understand the *etc.* in *I wish page to be p4_6 etc,*

Comment: Your labeling logic is not clear. Why does one group have 4 members (`p0_3`) and the other has 3 (`p4_6`)? Should we start again from zero once we hit the sexage values F00-F90?

Comment: I have tried to explain further. Please see above for more detail. Many thanks.

Comment: etc is short for etcetera which means a number of other things, in this case, continuously until the end, until M90 and F90 are reached.

Comment: Please do comment here if you think more information would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes = {}

for i in range(0, 5):
    indexes[i] = 'p0_4'

for i in range(5, 8):
    indexes[i] = 'p5_7'

nplt['page'] = [indexes.get(x) for x in nplt['age']]

where nplt['age'] = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

nplt
Out[169]: 
     sexage  npark16cd  population    page  age
0       M00  E26000001  146.631840    p0_4    0
1       M01  E26000001  122.677630    p0_4    1
2       M02  E26000001  127.645516    p0_4    2
3       M03  E26000001  138.313014    p0_4    3
4       M04  E26000001  150.898252    p0_4    4
5       M05  E26000001  149.086291    p5_7    5
6       M06  E26000001  145.075953    p5_7    6
7       M07  E26000001  159.893446    p5_7    7
```